Blender crashing when Distributing points on surfaces:
when using the distribute points on faces on objects that look more like figures, the program crashes each time.
I read an answer according to which the absolute size of the object is most important but even scaling does not help with the problem.
What are the performance bottlenecks for this operation?
(And how can I distribute points on faces in smaller parts as a procedure to circumvent these problems??)

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ to give it a try ? To limit the distribution, you can use the Selection socket to target a specific part of your model, based on Vertex Group, material or coordinates.
